# How to access usercontrol's radiobuttonlist from aspx.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, ascx

I'm having an impossible time getting the selected value of a radiobuttonlist control from an aspx.cs file. The radiobuttonlist control is inside of an .ascx file. I keep getting the System.NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any ideas?

I attempted to use the FindControl method several times changing it around as it would fail. Here's the last thing I tried:

```
protected void ClientsDropDownList_Selected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ConsultationFormControl.LoadClient(int.Parse(ClientsDropDownList.SelectedValue));    

            if (ClientsDropDownList.SelectedValue != "Please Select One")
            {
                UserControl US = FindControl("ConsultationFormControl") as UserControl;
                RadioButtonList rblMarStat = US.FindControl("rblMaritalStatus") as RadioButtonList;
                if (rblMarStat.SelectedValue == "Married")
                {
                    Response.Write("perfect");
                }
            }            
    }
```

Hope this helps.

James

Okay, guys, thanks for your help. Looks like we got it working. Thanks again, AVD. I remember creating a public property in the past for a couple of things. I just couldn't think tonight after all this coding without a break and it's late. That helped a lot. 
Peace, Bro. Peace fellows.

Comment: Show us your approach incl. the part where you're getting the `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=155

Comment: I was attempting to use the FindControl method. I changed it a lot attempting to get it to work. This is the last thing I tried when I came here with the exception:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a `public` property/method in user control that returns a `selected` value.

EDIT:

Add following property in user control's code behind,

```
public string SelectedValue
{
    get
    {
        return RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;
    }
}
```

To access the SelectedValue property from within the .aspx page,

```
string value=YourControlID1.SelectedValue;
```

OR use FindControl method,

```
 RadioButtonList rad = (RadioButtonList)YourControlID1.FindControl("RadioButtonList1");
 Response.Write(rad.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: I'm brain dead and will need to do this tomorrow. Could you give me an example in code to make it easier for me, Bro...Just in case

Comment: Dude, thanks, Bro. I have been coding for hours non-stop and just couldn't think anymore. That was a great help!

Comment: Hey, the second answer you gave me is pretty much what I had been trying in various forms. I just coded it as you have here (except renaming the controls according to need, of course) and it gave me the same null reference exception. But creating the public property worked flawlessly. :)

Comment: @JamesKhouriDevJunkie - Yes! Public property is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

You can access RadioButtonList by,
RadioButtonList rlist = (RadioButtonList)UserControlName.FindControl("RadioButtonList1");
 string str = rlist.SelectedValue;